# Concatenated many MP3 files together into 1 big file, but only the first one is played in Google Chrome (Firefox plays entire file)

Tags: google-chrome, html5-audio

So I'm just trying to play my mp3 through an HTML5 player - (just going to this URL in Chrome will do that):
https://orator.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/zenhabits.net.unsolved.mp3

It works in Firefox (plays all the way through), but it only plays the first 90 seconds in Chrome and then stops (I can't even resume playing).

[Edit 4/27/18 - The underlying issue is that I'm appending MP3 files together - it plays fine in media players except in Google Chrome, I've fixed up how to merge mp3s together properly and now it plays properly in Chrome]

[Pls ignore the rest of this - it was not a Range issue as I initially suspected]

Upon some inspection of the GET headers, I see that Chrome sends the "Range:" header (which causes a 206 response), but Firefox doesn't (it gets a 200 OK response).

Do I have to do something on the Azure blob storage to ignore this header? Or is there a better fix?

Request Headers (Chrome):

```
GET /mycontainer/zenhabits.net.unsolved.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Host: orator.blob.core.windows.net
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Range: bytes=0-
```

Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Length: 1
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Content-Range: bytes 113223-113223/1553061
Last-Modified: Tue, 24 Apr 2018 23:06:54 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "0x8D5AA38127F92B5"
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 1a22b618-c01e-0038-54a1-dcf734000000
x-ms-version: 2015-12-11
x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
x-ms-lease-state: available
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
x-ms-server-encrypted: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: x-ms-request-id,Server,x-ms-version,Content-Type,Last-Modified,ETag,x-ms-lease-status,x-ms-lease-state,x-ms-blob-type,x-ms-server-encrypted,Accept-Ranges
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Wed, 25 Apr 2018 14:25:02 GMT
```

I appreciate any insight into this.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to do something on the Azure blob storage to ignore this header? Or is there a better fix?

Unfortunately, it seems a compatibility for the Chrome browser for HTML5 video.

I also find a similar issue  [here](https://community.articulate.com/discussions/articulate-presenter/articulate-presenter-video-lagging-and-audio-dropping-when-using-chrome-as-browser#reply-505568) . Currently, if possible you could use the Firefox or Microsoft Edge as a work around.

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly is the incompatibility? I mean other mp3's hosted elsewhere play fine in Chrome.

Comment: Sorry @AmbroseLeung. I am not an export on Chrome browser.

Comment: No worries, I just found out that it's an issue with my MP3 file, I'm appending multiple smaller MP3 files together (like a string append), and Chrome doesn't like that - every other media player plays it fine though...